# Trying to make my middle mouse button to function as 3 different keys based on the elapsed time it has been pressed

Tags: windows, autohotkey

I'm using AHK and my main goal is to make my middle mouse button to function as it normally would if I pressed it once, but would trigger <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> or copy if I pressed and held it for 500ms and paste what is copied or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> if I kept on pressing for 1000ms

I have searched the Internet for a week but couldn't find a solution (maybe its because I'm new to this) but here's some codes I found that I believe would get it done but for some reason I couldn't get it to work.

Here's the code I found:

```
RCtrl::    
keyDown := A_TickCount
While GetKeyState("RCtrl", "P")
        Send {Ctrl Down}
    duration := A_TickCount - keyDown
    Send {Ctrl Up}
    if duration < 300
        Send {Enter}
    Return
```

and I have tried to modify some of it

```
MButton: :
    keyDown := A_TickCount
    While GetKeyState("MButton", "P")
    Send {^C}
    duration := A _TickCount - keyDown
    Send {Ctrl Up}
    if duration < 299
        Send {MButton}
    if duration < 500
        Send {^C}
    if duration < 1000
        Send {^V}
    Return
```

Comment: Title says Control key but the question body says the mouse button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#Requires AutoHotkey v1.1

MButton::    
    keyDown := A_TickCount  ; elapsed time in milliseconds since the system was started
    Keywait MButton       ; waits for MButton to be released
    duration := (A_TickCount - keyDown) ; elapsed time since the key has been pressed
    if (duration < 299)
        Send {MButton}
    else if (duration < 500)
        Send ^c 
    else
        Send ^v
Return
```

See [A_TickCount](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/Variables.htm#TickCount).

Comment: Please add a few sentences contextualization this code to make this a better, more complete answer.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. 
Thank you so much!